# Does uk.co.threefi.kafka-connect-http support SSL connection

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using open source jar (https://github.com/thomaskwscott/kafka-connect-http) to create kafka http sink connector to write message to a third party system. I could see Bad certificate error in receiver's end. SSl certificate is not sent as part of request. Does this open source jar NOT support SSL connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It uses `HttpUrlConnection`](https://github.com/thomaskwscott/kafka-connect-http/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/co/threefi/connect/http/sink/HttpApiWriter.java#L113) rather than `HttpsUrlConnection`, so I would guess no.

But you should really create a Github issue there asking this question.